# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Okay, so I've been grinding my brains this past week trying to understand what the problem is, but I just cant figure it out.

This is the error I've been having.

```
2250-2250/com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp, PID: 2250
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp/com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
        at com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setItemChecked(int, boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp.NavigationDrawer.selectItem(NavigationDrawer.java:135)
        at com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp.NavigationDrawer.onCreate(NavigationDrawer.java:43)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2159)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The NullPointerException goes away when I set If(savedInstanceState!=null). but my first fragment isn't inflated. What's the problem?

havingation drawer code:

```
package com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

 /**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawer extends Fragment {

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mListView;
private String[] nav_list;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

public NavigationDrawer() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        selectItem(0);
    }

   }
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

}


public void setup(int fragmentId,DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.Lists);
    nav_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.nav_item, R.id.text1, nav_list));
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                           }
                       }
    );

}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

public void selectItem(int position) {

  switch (position){
        case 0:

            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_frame,new Home_fragment());
                }
            });

        case 1:
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_frame,new Calender_fragment());
                }
            });

        case 2:
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_frame,new Profile_fragment());
                }
            });

    }
    mListView.setItemChecked(position,true);
    mListView.setSelection(position);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp.NavigationDrawer">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


></FrameLayout>



</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/Nav_dimens"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    class="com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp.NavigationDrawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

fragmentNavigationDrawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#EEE"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.cambridge.patils.citechcompanionapp.NavigationDrawer">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="168dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image"/>
<android.widget.ListView
    android:id="@+id/Lists"
    android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    </android.widget.ListView>
```

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: sorry updated! @NoName

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setItemChecked(int, boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: yes i realised that. i moved the setItemChecked line to the setup function but the null pointer exception moved to the setSelection function. on deleting that now it says the same for the closeDrawer line. what is happening?

Comment: Instead of moving it to setup function , Use it on onCreateView , but use view.findviewbyid instead of getView().findviewbyid , and view is view = inflator.inflate...